# Page layout issues with PHP , HTML, and CSS

Tags: php, html, css, formatting

For some reason my CSS is not formatting my div tags into the correct spots on the page. It works on all my other pages but this one has a lot more PHP in it than normal and I am wondering if that is the problem.
Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php
    require("protect/serverInfo.php");
    $myusername=$_POST[Email]; 
    $mypassword=$_POST[Password];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Email='$myusername' AND Password=$mypassword");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="customerHead">';
                <h1>  
                    <?php echo $row['Customer'] ?> 
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="customerInfoMain">
                 Company: <?php echo $row['Company'] ?><br />
                  State: <?php echo $row['State'] ?>
            </div>  
            <div class="customerCards">';
                 <a href ="something/<?php echo $row['imagePathFront'] ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $row['imagePathFront'] ?>" width="400px" height="303px" align="center" alt="" /></a>
                 <a href ="something/<?php echo $row['imagePathBack'] ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $row['imagePathBack'] ?>" width="400px" height="303px" align="center" alt="" /></a>
            </div>  
            <div class="customerComments">';
                <h5>Changes Made:</h5><br /> <?php echo $row['Comments'] ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php   
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
?>

</body>

</html
```

>

CSS

```
.customerCards{
    top: 150px;
    position: relative;
    width: 425px;
    border: 3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: silver;
    z-index:1;
}
.customerInfoMain{
    top: 200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    left: 520px;
    border: 3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: silver;
    z-index:2;
}
.customerComments{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    left: 580px;
    border: 3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: silver;
    z-index:2;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: -475px;
}
```

Source after page load

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">



<head>

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

<title>Untitled 1</title>

<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>



<body>

Wrong Username or Password

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: PHP runs on server side and is never present in the output. You need to look at the generated HTML (and possibly post it here)

Comment: I posted what the page source is after the page loadds

Comment: there's nothing for the CSS to work with on the markup you posted.

Comment: well, authentication is failing here thats why you are not seeing your css magic into action.

Comment: Well, you've posted what's generated by the `else`, how are we supposed to make sense of that?

Comment: But it is not failing. The page actually loads and everything

Comment: I dont know thats what I am confused by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its because your wrapper just starting if there is user.. 
But what happend if you put your wrapper around the PHP, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php
        require("protect/serverInfo.php");
        $myusername=$_POST[Email]; 
        $mypassword=$_POST[Password];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Email='$myusername' AND Password=$mypassword");
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count==1){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>

                <div class="customerHead">';
                    <h1>  
                        <?php echo $row['Customer'] ?> 
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="customerInfoMain">
                     Company: <?php echo $row['Company'] ?><br />
                      State: <?php echo $row['State'] ?>
                </div>  
                <div class="customerCards">';
                     <a href ="something/<?php echo $row['imagePathFront'] ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $row['imagePathFront'] ?>" width="400px" height="303px" align="center" alt="" /></a>
                     <a href ="something/<?php echo $row['imagePathBack'] ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $row['imagePathBack'] ?>" width="400px" height="303px" align="center" alt="" /></a>
                </div>  
                <div class="customerComments">';
                    <h5>Changes Made:</h5><br /> <?php echo $row['Comments'] ?> 
                </div>

        <?php   
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

"Then you should have a little bit of the CSS action?"

Answer (score 0):

Split the code by purpose functionality and calculations are not meant to be in the same place, html should be rendered last. Keeping on working like this will bring you a lot of trouble. Things should be done like this:

loginProcess.php contains:

    if(isset($_SESSION["user"]) {
$row = $_SESSION["user"];
}
    include("loginPage.php");
?>

and this is longinPage.php (you can include either of them in which on you want). Either include loginPage.php at the end of loginProcess.php or include loginProcess.php at the begining of loginPage.php

so loginPage.php contains

< !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
< html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

< head>
< meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
< title>Untitled 1
< link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
< /head>

< body>
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

```
    < div class="wrapper">

        < div class="customerHead">';

            <h1><!---you know the row from before---/>  

                <?php echo $row['Customer'] ?> 

            </h1>

        </div>

        <div class="customerInfoMain">

             Company: <?php echo $row['Company'] ?><br />
              State: <?php echo $row['State'] ?>

        </div>  
        <div class="customerCards">';

             <a href ="something/<?php echo $row['imagePathFront'] ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $row['imagePathFront'] ?>" width="400px" height="303px" align="center" alt="" /></a>

             < a href ="something/<?php echo $row['imagePathBack'] ?>" target="_blank">
```

< img src="" width="400px" height="303px" align="center" alt="" />

```
        </div>  

        <div class="customerComments">';

            <h5>Changes Made:</h5><br /> <?php echo $row['Comments'] ?> 

        </div>

    </div>

<?php   

    }

}
else {?>
     <form action="/loginProcess.php" (or loginPage.php if loginPage includes the loginProcess) method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="Email" value=""/>
            <input type="password" name="Password" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" value="login"/>
       </form>
<?php}?>
```

?>

first the login form will be shown and the user will input his credentials, those credentials will be checked and if they are ok the SESSION['user'] is set (remeber you need a session start for that) now as long as the session persists you will not need to request for login all the time. Anyway, if you do not want for some reason to fully separate Database Concerns/Process Concerns/Viewing Concerns, at leas you must separate the Process from the Viewing(Keeping Database concerns in the processing area). Checkout some frameworks online or try to find a way to write code with a little more care, otherwise you will keep on having useless problems that waste your time.